# How to destruct the last item in array in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to destruct the last item in an array if I don't know it's length in advance?

I have:

```
let response = {
  data: [
    { name: 'item1', level: 1 },
    { name: 'item2', level: 10 },
    { name: 'item3', level: 11 }
  ]
};
```

And I would like to get `name` and `level` of the last item in the array.

I know I can get an item with a specific index, for instance:

```
const {data: [,, {name, level}]} = response
```

But as the `data` array has a various length, it doesn't suit.

Answer (score 1):

What about getting the last element of the array and then destructure it?

```js
let response = {
  data: [
    { name: 'item1', level: 1 },
    { name: 'item2', level: 10 },
    { name: 'item3', level: 11 }
  ]
};

const {name, level} = response.data[response.data.length - 1];
console.log(name, level);
```